# Sitecore - WebP image not getting generated from CDN with Dianoga tool

Tags: azure, sitecore, webp, azure-cdn, sitecore9

**Version of Dianoga**
5.4.1

**Environment description**
Sitecore.NET 9.3.0
.NET Framework 4.7.2

**What configs you have enabled**

- Dianoga.DisableForSites.config
- Dianoga.Jpeg.config
- Dianoga.Log.config
- Dianoga.Png.config
- Dianoga.Svg.config
- Dianoga.WebP.CDN.config
- Dianoga.WebP.config

**Web.config changes:**
I`ve replaced in sitecore_media.ashx type to "Dianoga.MediaRequestHandler, Dianoga" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler"

**What you expected to see, versus what you actually saw**

**Expected:** To see images being pulled down in webp format

**Actual:** Images are received in original formats (jpeg, png, etc), but not in webp.

**Logs files:**
All logs files are empty.

**Comments**
After deploy on CD in Azure MediaProvider adds extension webp as a URL param. This should trigger the webp optimizer in the MediaRequestHandler. But the MediaProvider doesn’t appear to run. On my local envirement I don`t use CDN and Dianoga works fine. And I am probably missing something?

Comment: Hi @Mykyta, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   Your image files are not getting converted because there might be a *`conflict in the Sync/Async strategy`*. Also, since the **‘Dianoga.WebP.CDN.config’** configuration in the CDN is **enabled**, you will have to **disable the ‘Dianoga.Strategy.MediaCacheAsync.config’** setting.

Also, ensure that **‘MediaOptimization’** is enabled by enabling the **‘Dianoga.Strategy.GetMediaStreamSync.config.disabled’ config setting** and the one stated above. This will ensure that the `optimization will occur synchronously when the images are requested`, thus ensuring the successful conversion of image files.

•   Please check the **‘Accept’** header configured in the CDN to be included in the **cache key as the list of accepted media formats is mentioned in this header**. This header tells which image format conversions are possible. For e.g.: - `the header can be ‘image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8’ which means that the browser supports ‘WebP’ image format`.

Also, as stated by you in the question, you seem to have **enabled** the **`‘Next-gen formats support’`**, but in that too, you will have to **change the line ‘’** to **‘’** in the **web.config file**.

For more details, kindly refer to the below documentation link for more steps to be followed regarding this: -

**https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga#optimization-strategies**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure CDN (Microsoft) or Azure Front Door Classic with Azure CDN (Microsoft), `Accept` header is not passed to the Origin server. Dianoga needs `Accept` header to understand whether it supports nextgen image formats or not.

If the pages are not routed via Azure CDN, then `Accept` header will be passed to the origin server only for the page requests. Dianoga and Sitecore will generate the media link with Extension query param `extension=webp,{other image formats}`. If this query param is available, then Dianoga will be able to generate the `webp` format without reading the `Accept` header of media request.

**Option 1**: Upgrade Azure CDN to Verizon Premium (costly) and it passes the header back to Origin server and Dianoga will be able to optimize and send the `webp` Images.

**Option 2**: If you have a rule engine in your CDN, create a rule to send the Accept header in a different header name and use that header name in Dianoga to generate the `webp` format. This needs a rule engine before the requests hit the Azure CDN.
[Option to enable webp format using Azure CDN](https://www.nehemiahj.com/2022/08/sitecore-dianoga-with-azure-cdn.html)